# Cordova Display Issues

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am a french student, and I am currently working for a company, and they asked me to develop an application for Galaxy Tab 2 (Android 4.0.3). Since it's not an app they are going to sell, I'm alone on this. I chose to experiment with AngularJs and Cordova.

My issue is that my application displays fine in Mozilla, not well at all in Chrome, and when I build an apk with cordova, the app is very slow and don't display in horizontal view, only in vertical ...

I really don't know where to look, is there any known issues about that kind of things ? Any tips & tricks & best practices to avoid this issue ?

Thank you for your time, and your future advices.

Answer (score 0):

Early this year a client call me to make a application, always love Cordova and i wanna try Angular, then i make the application using both technologies, in resume i can tell you this:

1. I development app using cordova since version 1, and testing some technologies like, plain html boilerplate, jQuery Mobile, jQmobi and Backbone. All that technologies goes very slow or the maintainability, reusability, etc. had very big issue. From that technologies the best was Backbone. and AngularJS win that battle and in that project i use this technologies and get a very good performance, maintainability, reusability, etc.
2. The start configuratión was very complex (first time using angular, and integrate with cordova was a pain in the ass ), you friend here is [Brian Ford](https://github.com/btford), he have a lot of directive to the main plugins of cordova, and fix some basic issue in the start configuration
3. In middle of the project, the client request support a web application also. Then i take advantage and refactor the code, currently is a pretty folder structure, is a combination of yeoman angular generator, and cordova create project default. where the dist folder of angular yeoman is the www folder of cordova. Somethin like this:

Cordova Project
├── [Gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9629c32635426983ba49)
├── README.md
├── app
├── bower.json
├── config.xml
├── hooks
├── merges
├── node_modules
├── out
├── package.json
├── platforms
├── plugins
└── www

Add in a gist the grunt file to this project.

In resume: Is a good option, if i had to make another app multiplatform, with low cost. In the 100% of the case i choose this architecture.

Over the display horizontal is Android development configuration you must set in the Manifiest to accept both orientation.